# overriding tostring() method and passing object reference without getting hash

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference, overriding

I'm trying to override the `toString()` method and print without the hash. When I use my `tostring()` method when trying to print it requires me to create another object like `asset server = new asset();`. When I do this and use just `server` it returns the default constructor or it gives an error when I use  `server[i]`. The code I have written returns this:

```
 `ant -f C:\\Users\\kalle\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\assign7 -
  Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
  init:
  Deleting: C:\Users\kalle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\assign7\build\built-
  jar.properties
  deps-jar:
  Updating property file: 
  C:\Users\kalle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\assign7\build\built-
  jar.properties
  compile:
  run:
  server switch etc.
  0
  vendor model number
  serial number
  1

  driver.asset@15db9742
  server
  server0
  10
  a1
  1
   driver.asset@15db9742
   server
  server1
  20
  a2
  1
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`
```

Here is my code:`

```
 package driver;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        asset basic = new asset();
        asset[] server = new asset[2];
        server[0]= new asset("server", 10, "server0", "a1", 1);
        server[1]= new asset("server", 20, "server1", "a2",1);
        for (i=0;i<server.length;i++){
            System.out.println(basic);
            System.out.println(server[i].Type);
            System.out.println(server[i].Name);
            System.out.println(server[i].ID);
            System.out.println(server[i].Serial);
            System.out.println(server[i].PID);
        }
    }
}

public class asset {
    String Type;
    int ID;
    String Name;
    String Serial;
    int PID;
    int i;

    public String getType(){
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String Type){
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public int getID(){ 
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int getid){
        Integer.toString(ID);
        this.ID= ID;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }

     public void setName(String Name){
         this.Name = Name;
     }

     public String getSerial(){
         return Serial;
     }

    public void setSerial(String Serial){
        this.Serial = Serial;
    }

    public int getPID() {        
        return PID;    
    }

    public void setPID(int getPID) {
        Integer.toString(PID);
        this.PID= PID;     
    }

    public asset(){
        Name ="vendor model number";
        ID =0;
        Serial ="serial number";
        Type ="server switch etc.";
        PID =1;
        System.out.println( Type + "\n " + ID + "\n " + Name + "\n " + Serial + "\n " + PID + "\n ");}

        asset(String Type, int ID, String Name, String Serial, int PID){
        this.Type= Type;
        this.Name= Name;
        this.PID= PID;
        this.Serial= Serial;
        this.ID= ID;        
    }

    public String toString (asset[] a){
        getType();
        getID();
        setID(ID);
        getName();
        getSerial();
        getPID();
        setPID(PID);

       return this.Type + " " + this.ID + " " + this.Name + " " + this.Serial + " " + this.PID + " ";
    }
}
```

How do i get rid of the "driver.asset@15db9742".

Comment: `Object.toString` doesn't take in any parameters.

Comment: Your code formatting is horrendous and you don't follow the Java naming conventions (`asset`, as a class, should be called `Asset`). Are you using an IDE?

Comment: the weirdest thing is that the ***a*** parameter in the ***toString*** method is used nowhere....

Comment: You're not overriding toString correctly.  The signature of the method should be `public String toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to override the `toString` method is to have the following structure :

```
public String toString(){
    // return String type
}
```

For you (call `getXY()` does nothing alone) :

```
public String toString (){  
   return this.Type + " " + this.ID + " " + this.Name + " " + this.Serial + " " + this.PID + " ";
}
```

---

Also, to follow conventions, you'd better :

- name classes in *CamelCase*  : `asset` -> `Asset`
- name attributs (&parameter&variables) follow *camelCase* : `type`, `id`, `name`, `pid`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i;
asset basic = new asset();
asset[] server = new asset[2];
server[0]= new asset("server", 10, "server0", "a1", 1);
server[1]= new asset("server", 20, "server1", "a2",1);
System.out.println(basic); // just delete this line.
for (i=0;i<server.length;i++)
{
System.out.println(server[i].Type);
System.out.println(server[i].Name);
System.out.println(server[i].ID);
System.out.println(server[i].Serial);
System.out.println(server[i].PID);}

}
```

You kept printing out the value of basic, that's probably why it churned out the the string hash name instead of the actual stored value. Just take the System.out.println(basic); out of the for loop? Even better, delete the line altogether!

Comment: You are amazing and thank you. But why I have a question, Why does it print out the default constructor anyway without telling it too?

Comment: Because you didn't call your override .toString() method. This link should help: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/